# more details in Jboss console?

Tags: logging, jboss, centos

I am new to JBOSS 4.2. when I start the server on CentOS 5.4(final). it give me simple log in its console. How I can show deployment errors, messages that wars print in Jboss log ?

Thanks in advance

```
   15:46:24,207 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: /home/mebada/jad/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server  
      /nops01/log
   15:46:24,207 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: /home/mebada/jad/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server
    /nops01/tmp
    15:46:24,208 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
    15:46:25,849 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0,Sun Microsystems Inc.
     15:46:25,849 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM 1.6.0-b09,Sun Microsystems Inc.
     15:46:25,849 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Linux 2.6.18-164.el5,i386
     15:46:26,674 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
     15:46:41,567 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
     15:46:41,569 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is the JBoss boot/console log. Judging by those paths, you should find the main log file in `/home/mebada/jad/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/<servername>/log/server.log`. Substitute `<servername>` appropriately - probably with `default` if you haven't specified the `-c` flag when you started up.

The `<servername>/conf/jboss-log4j.xml` defines the specific logging configuration, including which log messages go to which logs.

Comment: yes I did, but when I remove it couldn't start. I use customized server settings

Comment: @worldpython: If you use custom settings, then `<servername>` is the name of the directory under `jboss-4.2.3.GA/server` which contains your settings